# Execute CMD Command with QProcess silently

Tags: c++, qt

I wanted to execute some cmd command and then save their result for further work. I used system() for my purposes but it doesn't work silently. When system() executes my commands, a console window will appear. I didn't want console windows to appear to the user. How can I overwrite the following function with qprocess to execute my cmd command silently?

```
bool MainWindow::CreateTemporaryFiles()
{
    QString command_description = "wmic logicaldisk get description > C:\\Users\\Test\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\description.log";
    system(command_description.toStdString().c_str());

    QString command_device_name = "wmic logicaldisk get DeviceID > C:\\Users\\Test\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\names.log";
    system(command_device_name.toStdString().c_str());

    QString command_free_space = "wmic logicaldisk get FreeSpace > C:\\Users\\Test\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\space.log";
    system(command_free_space.toStdString().c_str());

    QString command_size = "wmic logicaldisk get size > C:\\Users\\Test\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\size.log";
    system(command_size.toStdString().c_str());

    QString command_file_system = "wmic logicaldisk get FileSystem > C:\\Users\\Test\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\file.log";
    system(command_file_system.toStdString().c_str());

    QString command_sysname = "wmic logicaldisk get SystemName > C:\\Users\\Test\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\sysname.log";
    system(command_sysname.toStdString().c_str());

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [popen](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) to run a command and get the output.

You can find an example [here](https://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node12.html).

`QProcess` allows you to do that also. QProcess [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) explain how to do it. Several examples [here](https://cpp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/QProcess/closeWriteChannel/cpp-qprocess-closewritechannel-method-examples.html).

(Edited.)

If you need direct Windows, you have a complete example in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output).

This was shown as example.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        FILE *pipein_fp, *pipeout_fp;
        char readbuf[80];

        /* Create one way pipe line with call to popen() */
        if (( pipein_fp = popen("ls", "r")) == NULL)
        {
                perror("popen");
                exit(1);
        }

        /* Create one way pipe line with call to popen() */
        if (( pipeout_fp = popen("sort", "w")) == NULL)
        {
                perror("popen");
                exit(1);
        }

        /* Processing loop */
        while(fgets(readbuf, 80, pipein_fp))
                fputs(readbuf, pipeout_fp);

        /* Close the pipes */
        pclose(pipein_fp);
        pclose(pipeout_fp);

        return(0);
}
```

Comment: C++ has a lot more possibilities than just using popen/fgets

Comment: I wanted to implement my code with QProcess. I am using windows.

Comment: @thunderlightning in my response you have a link to an example to do this with Qt. You are using `system` so I supposed you could use `popen`: both are there for Windows (though not for Universal Windows Platform build.)

Comment: @Xatyrian why don't you show which ones? That's what this site is meant for. I try to give something similar to what is in the question. If you want to help, show those alternative solutions. Your comment doesn't help.